# Connect to SQL Server (on Linux) failed

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu

I have installed the new SQL Server on Ubuntu in Virtual Machine.
I can connect from SSMS on Windows computer to this SQL Server, but cannot connect from another computer.

> Failed to connect to server 192.168.0.10.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Both computers are in the same domain.
What to correct? what is wrong?

ping from both windows computers to Ubuntu works OK.

Comment: Named Pipes are available on Windows *only*. Use the server's IP address or name and make sure you have enabled TCP/IP connections on the client. How did you try to connect? What connection string did you use?

Comment: I am trying to connect in SSMS: using IP address and sql server user/password

Comment: Click on "Options" on the connection string and ensure the `Network Protocol` is `TCP/IP`. I assume you use the *VM's* IP, not the host's? Is the VM accessible over the network ?

Comment: Yes, I use the IP of Linux which is installed in VM. I ran ifconfig in Ubuntu to be sure.

Comment: And that's the same subnet as your local network? Can you ping that IP? SSMS will try multiple protocols before failing. It may have failed with TCP/IP first and tried Named Pipes second.

Comment: Finally, make sure you use the SSMS version compatible with SQL Server on Linux, That's 17.0 RC or something. Perhaps the version you use doesn't know how to connect to SQL on Linux.

Comment: SSMS->Connection dialog->Options: Network Protocol = <default> only, no any other.

Comment: Yes, I use the latest SSMS 16, but ot works on other computers. OK, need to reinstall it with 17 rc1

Comment: Then change it to `TCP/IP` and try again. Default means "use whatever the default is", it's not a specific protocol

Comment: that's NOT the correct version. The correct version is [17.0 RC1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx). 16.5.1 is the production version targetting the current range of SQL Servers

Comment: BUT: on the same computer my c# app cannot connect to the Ubuntu SQL Server too. But on the other computer it can.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos Version of SSMS does not matter. Haven't tried the newest one, but I assume MS just fixed some menus/dialogs/windows to recognize SSOL.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go through the following troubleshooting list:

1. Verify that SQL is up and running: systemctl status mssql-server
2. Verify it is responding: sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "SELECT @@Version"
3. Verify that VM is connected to the host: ping 192.168.0.10 // that is from host
4. Verify that port is opened (from host): PortQry.exe -n 192.168.0.10 -e 1433

Assuming you do not have any other firewall rules and all verification passes you can do from your host:

```
sqlcmd -S 192.168.0.10  -U SA -Q "SELECT @@Version"
```

BTW, I'm not networking guru, but Zero in your VM's IP address looks strange:
192.168.**_ 0 _**.10

Comment: Zero is ok in the IP.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be related to the way you have configured your virtualized operating system network.

It would help me know which virtualization software you are using.

Check the virtual network interface and make sure it is in bridge mode with the physical network interface.

All machines has to be in the same subnet.

Comment: The strange problem is: I run SSMS, connect to Ubuntu SQL Server, do some actions, all is ok, disconnect. In some minutes I cannot connect from the same computer to the SQL Server, I receive the error message (see the start post)

Comment: Which virtualization software you are using?

Comment: Virtual Machine

Comment: Have you verified that the virtual network interface is in bridge mode?

Comment: Yes, it was done. The matter is: I can connect from other windows computers, no problem.

Comment: About your first comment. When it stop accepting connections check, at the same time, if others services like SSH are accepting incoming connections.